Git Repo hierarchy
I have a Git server(on bitBucket if it matters) that is structured with a ton of project folders.
I'd like to set it up so there are sub directories essentially that are their own repo.
essentially what I have is
Main <-- lots and lots of repos

What I'd like is:
         | <-- Software A <--some repos
     Main| <-- Software B <--some other repos
         | <-- Software C <--some different repos

Where you could clone any of the Software A/B/C folders if necessary, but more likely each Dev would just clone the repos under the Software A/B/C folders.
Is this possible?  Or would I have to set up individual servers for each Software A/B/C? I guess the other alternative is to create a new server, then set up the individual repos in that server, and inside each repo include a submodule to the software I want in the Software A/B/C repos?
I tried creating repos under main, but I can't create the project repo in those.  They are treated like individual projects. I want to group projects by the software used to develop them without having multiple repository servers if possible.

Have you checked git submodule?  It sounds like exactly what you're going for.

The recommended approach would be working with "BitBucket Projects" , for exemple your containers (parent repositories) will look like this :
BitBucket Server
├── Project: Software A
│   ├── repo1
│   ├── repo2
│   └── repo3
├── Project: Software B
│   ├── repo4
│   └── repo5
└── Project: Software C
├── repo6
└── repo7

Each repository would need to be maintained separately.
To implement the recommended approach (BitBucket Projects):

In BitBucket, go to Projects → Create Project
Name it "Software A" (or whatever you prefer)
Create repositories within that project.
Repeat for Software B and C.

